# input type file, trigger the popup by a button click only

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, input-type-file

I have this file upload control:

[image]

Which has this markup:

```
<div class="controls">
    <input name="attachments[]"  id="attachment_control" runat="server" type="file" /><br />     
    <div id="fileuploads" runat="server"></div>
</div>
```

I want to somehow fix this control to have the popup shown only on the <kbd>Browse</kbd> button click. As it is now, anywhere you'll click in the control, the upload popup will be shown, but I want only when the user will click on the button, the popup to be shown.

How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at this: oldie but goodie http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Comment: @erisco Your edit is being discussed on Meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299246/176646

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#nofile").click(function() {
      $("#fileuploads").click();
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="controls">
     <label>File</lable>
     <input type="button" value="Upload" id="nofile"  width="30px"/>
     <input type="file" id="fileuploads" runat="server" style="display: none;" />
     </div>
```

This might help

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="controls">
 <label>File</lable>
 <input type="button" value="Upload" id="nofile"  width="30px"/>
 <input type="file" id="fileuploads" runat="server" style="display: none;" />
 </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $("#nofile").click(function() {
  $("#fileuploads").click();
  });
  </script>
```